# How can I call static method from static method without using class name?

Tags: python, static-methods

Example of code:
How i run this code without using 'A'

```
    class A:
        @staticmethod
        def a():
            print('a')
    
        @staticmethod
        def b():
            print('b')
            print(**A**.a())
    
    A.a()
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Why do you have a problem with using class name?

Comment: why do you need to do this, and why cant you just have the a function outside of the A class if you dont want to have to call the class name???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer the class with `__class__`.

try this:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        print('a')

    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print('b')
        __class__.a() # notice here we're not using `A`
    
A.b()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the decorator @classmethod , an argument cls gets passed to the function which can refer to the classname without explicitly coding the class name, assuming you want to call this function from another static method of the same class. If the use case defers please say so as this is probably only a fit because you want to call it from a static method of the same Class.

```
class A:

    @classmethod
    def a(cls, args...):
      pass

    @classmethod
    def b(cls, args...):
      cls.a()


A.b()  # notice that you dont need an instance of the class to call a class method only the class.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way might be to create a package, so a folder (e.g. src) containing an even empty _*init*_.py file, an A.py file containing your class and, above the folder, a main.py file containing the line

```
from src.A import *
```

then you can call

```
a()
```

without the class name